# PHP regex format?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regex format to check the following type string:

```
40/4
```

The following features I need:

- the string will be exactly four characters long
- 1st character will have to be 1-9
- 2nd character will have to be 0-9
- 3rd character will have to be a forward slash (/)
- and 4th character will have to be 0-9

Here's what I ended up writing:

```
"/^.{4}$[1-9][0-9][\/][1-9]/"
```

Please help me to write the correct format.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It will be like below:

```
/^[1-9][0-9]\/[0-9]$/
```